# Integer Factorization - Code does not work

Tags: java

If I type in 100 it should be look like this: (2,2,5,5)
But it is not working.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class kgV {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        boolean isPrime = true;

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int number = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());


        for(int i=2; number>0; i++){
            for(int j=2; j<i; j++){
                if(i % j == 0){
                isPrime = false;
            }
        }

        if(isPrime && number % i == 0){
            number = number / i;
            factors.add(i);
        }

        isPrime = true;

        }
        System.out.println(factors.toString());
    }
}
```

This is how it should work

```
100 = 2x2x5x5
27= 3x3x3
30= 2x3x5
```

Comment: You should code with english names, at least when showing it to foreigners.

Comment: I'm flagging this as "very low quality". There is no question other than the indirect question "Why is this not working?", the formatting is bad and the last two lines .. I don't know how to react to them. Remove this post, it doesn't belong here.

Comment: The question is WHY this is not working

Comment: `zahl / x` = `0`, solve for `x`.

Comment: Instead of typing nonsense at the end, you could post what results you're getting.

Comment: NO results... I can just type a new number in it

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
public class NewClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  ArrayList<Integer> faktoren = new ArrayList<Integer>();    

  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  int zahl = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

  for (int i = 2; i <= zahl; i++) {
      while (zahl % i == 0) {
        faktoren.add(i);
        zahl /= i;
      }
  }
  System.out.println(faktoren.toString());
  }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        ArrayList<Integer> faktoren = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int zahl = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        // While number is not 1 check for factors
        while (zahl != 1) {
            // Check each number till zahl for possible factor
            for (int i = 2; i <= zahl; i++) {
                if (zahl % i == 0) {
                    // update number and add factor
                    zahl = zahl / i;
                    faktoren.add(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // Prime number will contain only itself in faktoren array
        boolean prim = faktoren.size() == 1;
        System.out.println(faktoren.toString());
    }
}
```